# Reference declaration file (.d.ts) in a .ts file, with compiler "module" option set to none

Tags: typescript

I have setup an ASP.net core MVC project with TS. I want to use TS without using any module system. Just "clean" compiled TS=>JS.

The problem I am facing, is that I can't reference a declaration file (.d.ts) in a .ts file, without using "import".

If I do use "import" code completion and type checking works, but because I have configured my project not to use any "module" system, compiler complains saying: **"Cannot use imports, exports or module augmentations when '--module' is 'none'**

I've already tried using triple slash directives [Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) and [using @types, typeRoots and types in tsconfig.json files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)  but no luck.

VS2017(same with VS Code) doesn't seem to be able resolve the referenced file.

I've set up a rudimentary project which demonstrates the problem
https://github.com/gtrifidis/Asp.netCoreTypescriptDemo/tree/master/TypeScriptDemo

Any help/idea would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that TypeScript doesn't find your d.ts file, but because in your case the file index.d.ts of `i18next` is written in the module fashion, and is supposed to be used only with `import`. Luckily, it is very easy to fix this; all you have to do is to go to index.d.ts and remove the last line:

```
....
declare const i18next: i18next.i18n;
export = i18next; // <- remove this line
```

And then you can go ahead and remove the `import` in your LocalizationTest.ts, and it will compile just fine.

#### Update

Or, as noted by @AluanHaddad, instead of removing it and create your own definition, you should submit a PR that adds a new line:

```
....
declare const i18next: i18next.i18n;
export = i18next;
export as namespace i18next; // <- add this instead
```

Comment: This is correct, but there are two things that should be noted. 1: the npm package now ships with its own type definitions (which are still wrong in the manner you described). 2: There is a UMD bundle distributed as part of that package, allowing you to use it as a global, but the type declarations do not reflect that. Therefore, the correct fix is to submit a PR that uses the UMD style declaration syntax so, instead of removing the export clause, add `export as namespace i18next;`

Comment: @AluanHaddad and Mu-Tsun-Tsai thank you for your help. Here is the pull request [PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/36564) just FYI in case you were interested.